# Custom Progress as Step - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make something like this:

[image]

I'd try to draw this using `Canvas.drawArc(...)` but I failed.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I created a view that can draw the shape that you want.
It starts by creating a path for one of the quarters, and rotating the canvas by 90 degrees to draw the path 4 times. The `Paint` used to draw the `Path` is determined by the `progress / maxProgress`.

I used a second path to denote the region of the canvas to clip out when drawing, so that there are empty spaces between the quarters.

Finally, the text can be drawn in the middle after restoring the canvas rotation and clipping.

```
public class CustomProgressView extends View {

    private int progress;
    private int maxProgress;

    private float arcWidth;
    private float arcPadding;
    private Paint paintPositive;
    private Paint paintNegative;
    private Paint paintText;

    private Path path;
    private Path clipPath;

    private ProgressListener listener;

    public CustomProgressView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CustomProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public CustomProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        arcWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        arcPadding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 6, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        paintPositive = new Paint();
        paintPositive.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintPositive.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paintPositive.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintNegative = new Paint();
        paintNegative.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paintPositive.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paintNegative.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintText = new Paint();
        paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintText.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

        progress = 0;
        maxProgress = 10;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        float diameter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());

        RectF ovalOuter = new RectF(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
        RectF ovalInner = new RectF(ovalOuter.left + arcWidth, ovalOuter.top + arcWidth, ovalOuter.right - arcWidth, ovalOuter.bottom - arcWidth);

        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(ovalOuter.centerX(), ovalOuter.top);
        path.addArc(ovalOuter, 270, 90);
        path.lineTo(ovalInner.right, ovalInner.centerY());
        path.addArc(ovalInner, 0, -90);
        path.lineTo(ovalOuter.centerX(), ovalOuter.top);

        clipPath = new Path();
        clipPath.addRect(ovalOuter.left, ovalOuter.centerY() - arcPadding / 2, ovalOuter.right, ovalOuter.centerY() + arcPadding / 2, Path.Direction.CW);
        clipPath.addRect(ovalOuter.centerX() - arcPadding / 2, ovalOuter.top, ovalOuter.centerX() + arcPadding / 2, ovalOuter.bottom, Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float perc = (float) progress / (float) maxProgress;
        int state = 0;
        if (perc < 0.25) {
            state = 1;
        } else if (perc < 0.5) {
            state = 2;
        } else if (perc < 0.75) {
            state = 3;
        } else {
            state = 4;
        }

        RectF bounds = new RectF();
        path.computeBounds(bounds, true);

        // Draw Circle
        canvas.save();
        // Clip padding
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

        canvas.drawPath(path, state == 1 ? paintPositive : paintNegative);

        canvas.rotate(90, bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
        canvas.drawPath(path, state == 2 ? paintPositive : paintNegative);

        canvas.rotate(90, bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
        canvas.drawPath(path, state == 3 ? paintPositive : paintNegative);

        canvas.rotate(90, bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
        canvas.drawPath(path, state == 4 ? paintPositive : paintNegative);
        canvas.restore();

        // Draw Progress
        String text = String.valueOf(progress);

        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

        float x = bounds.left - textBounds.width() / 2;
        float y = bounds.bottom + textBounds.height() / 2;
        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paintText);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        int oldProgress = this.progress;
        this.progress = progress;

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onProgressChanged(oldProgress, progress);
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMaxProgress() {
        return maxProgress;
    }

    public void setMaxProgress(int maxProgress) {
        this.maxProgress = maxProgress;
        invalidate();
    }

    public ProgressListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {
        void onProgressChanged(int oldProgress, int newProgress);
    }
}
```